# Error in deploying SSAS cube to SQL Server Analysis

Tags: sql-server, ssas, analysis, cubes

I am having issue deploying SSAS package to SQL Server Analysis. It is complaining of duplicates keys whereas the column is referencing is not a primary key column. I queried the dimension table to see that the primary keys have same values in the affected columns which is normal and possible. The attribute usage and type property are already set to regular in SSDT. Please find the error I am receiving below. I will appreciate an idea to fix this issue. Thank you.[image]

Errors and Warnings from Response

> Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation
>   in the transaction failed.    Errors in the OLAP storage engine: A
>   duplicate attribute key has been found when processing: Table:
>   'dwh_Dim_By_Answers', Column: 'QB_AnswerText', Value: 'hazard'. The
>   attribute is 'QB Answer Text'.

Answer (score 0):

Their is two solutions for this issue :

1. to avoid key duplicate error when processing a dimension you just need to set the dimension property  ProcessingGroup to ByAttribute instead of ByTable.
2. Force SSAS to ignore key duplicate error by setting KeyDupplicate to IgnoreError in dimension key errors tab. To achieve this go to SSMS OR SSVS -> process -> in process tab click change setings -> dimension key errors -> Use costume error configuration -> set KeyDupplicate to IgnoreError.

visit : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3476/sql-server-analysis-services-ssas-processing-error-configurations/